# null == null returning false?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

Can anyone provide any ideas why my null check is evaluating incorrectly?

It should also be pointed out, that if i is not null, the evaluation is correct.  I'm not sure what else is relevant, but let me know what other details I need to provide.

```
foreach (var item in selectedItems)
{
    var i = inspectionItems.Keys.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InspectionItemId == item.InspectionItemId);
    if (i != null)
    {
        // Process i
     }
     else
     {
       // create
     }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not to ask the obvious; but did you clean and rebuild so there aren't any weird debug symbols left over? That behavior seems very strange.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, after clean and rebuild, strange behavior persists.

Comment: Is there some special operator overload defined for `==`?  What does `Object.Equals(i, null)` return? Please show the class/struct definition for `i`.

Comment: Thanks @NathanA, I did overload the == operator for this class, and it looks like I failed to include a null check

Comment: @JohnieKarr Lucky Guess :)

Comment: @NathanA, you missed the point by posting as comment :)

Comment: @davidc, no I'm not defining what null means.

Comment: @Rahul Moderators love to condem questions posed as answers, so I took the less risky option.

Comment: @NathanA, Give me a +1; I am posting your comment as answer LOL .. :)

Comment: Fine. fine.  I've posted my comments as an answer!  (hands raised in the air!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that you overloaded the `==` operator.  The result of `Object.Equals(i, null)` could confirm that.

If you are overloading the `==` operator, it's possible your logic is incorrectly handling the `null` case.

Comment: You got scared by seeing my comment :). +1 nice catch though.

Answer (score 0):

One [devious] way to get this to happen would be :-

```
    public enum Cheat
    {
        @null = 0,
        foo = 1,
        bar = 2
    }
```

If you assign `Cheat.@null` to `i` you get the watch values you show.

[image]

What is the type of `i`?  Either it displays in the debugger as `null` or you've done something else in that class that could cause `==` to fail.

Comment: Note to self; delete *any* code that ever looks like that. Talk about a hard bug to find.

Comment: Yeah Nathan should post his comment as the answer.